# Does a PropertyChangedEventHandler keep my custom control from being garbage collected?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am fairly new to WPF, and I wondered listening for property changes will keep my custom control from being garbage collected...

Essentially, I listen to events like this:

```
obj.PropertyChanged += this.The_PropertyChanged;
```

I am afraid that the control in which I execute the code not be able to be garbage collected while `obj` still exists, as `obj.PropertyChanged` holds a reference to `this`. Is this correct? If so, what is the correct way to avoid this? If I am informed correctly, there is no `Dispose()` method that could be overridden to be called when the Control is removed from the screen, so there is no obvious location to remove `this.The_PropertyChanged` from `obj.PropertyChanged`...

Comment: First of, are you sure you need this? Normally the PropertyChanged event is subscribed to by Binding objects, not by your code.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are correct. obj will have a reference to "this" and therefore "this" will not get garbage collected.   The solution is:

```
obj.PropertyChanged -= this.The_PropertyChanged;
```

and you would place that code where "this" is Closed, Disposed, or else wise no longer going to be around.

So for the control, if the Window that hosts the control is closed that could be where you place the code.

Comment: Thank you :) There has to be a better way than putting the responsibility on whoever uses the control in their code, though? Should the control listen on the windows events when it is added or something like that?

Comment: The control doesn't listen to the events.  The control is informed when the event occurs.  The += just adds that event handler to the list of functions to be called when the event is fired.  Try adding the same event handler several times for a single event.  You'll note that the handler will get called once for each time you added it.  Think of it more like the handler is a subscriber and the event is the publisher.  Just like in the real world if you no longer want to get Time magazine mailed to you have to tell them to stop sending it.